# Estimated cost through web3.js

Tags: solidity, web3js, gas

I have written a web3 implementation. The code below invokes a method of solidity contract that writes some value to blockchain:

```
var Coursetro = CoursetroContract.at('0x3958c21a7037d4a53c2990834c59ca3dcb00d988');
var fileName = "filename.pdf";
var identifier = uuid.v4();
console.log("uuid is " + identifier);

Coursetro.setFile(identifier,fileName,"hash...",function(error, result){
  if(!error)
  {
    console.log("Transaction submitted" + result);
  }
  else{
    console.log("Error " + error);
  }
});
```

How can I get a estimated cost for the "setFile" transaction and provide my gas limit and price ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web3js provides an [`estimateGas`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethestimategas) function for each transaction. You only need to suffix your transaction with `estimateGas` like `myContract.myMethod.estimateGas(arg1, arg2, {options})`

Here is an example for your case:

**web3js 0.20.x** ([documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethestimategas))

```
var Coursetro = CoursetroContract.at('0x3958c21a7037d4a53c2990834c59ca3dcb00d988');
var fileName = "filename.pdf";
var identifier = uuid.v4();
console.log("uuid is " + identifier);

web3.eth.getGasPrice(function(error, result){ 
    var gasPrice = Number(result);
    console.log("Gas Price is " + gasPrice + " wei"); // "10000000000000"

    Coursetro.setFile.estimateGas(identifier, fileName, "hash...", {from: 0x, ...}).then(function(result) {
        var gas = Number(result);

        console.log("gas estimation = " + gas + " units");
        console.log("gas cost estimation = " + (gas * gasPrice) + " wei");
        console.log("gas cost estimation = " + TestContract.web3.fromWei((gas * gasPrice), 'ether') + " ether");
    });
});
```

**web3js 1.0.x** ([documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-estimategas))

If you are using **web3js 1.0**, it's a bit different you have to make the call like that `myContract.methods.myMethod(arg1, arg2, ...).estimateGas({options})`

```
var Coursetro = CoursetroContract.at('0x3958c21a7037d4a53c2990834c59ca3dcb00d988');
var fileName = "filename.pdf";
var identifier = uuid.v4();
console.log("uuid is " + identifier);

web3.eth.getGasPrice(function(error, result){ 
    var gasPrice = Number(result);
    console.log("Gas Price is " + gasPrice + " wei"); // "10000000000000"

    Coursetro.methods.setFile.(identifier, fileName, "hash...").estimateGas.then({from: 0x}, function(result) {
        var gas = Number(result);

        console.log("gas estimation = " + gas + " units");
        console.log("gas cost estimation = " + (gas * gasPrice) + " wei");
        console.log("gas cost estimation = " + TestContract.web3.fromWei((gas * gasPrice), 'ether') + " ether");
    });
});
```

Of course, the gasPrice is a median value, the client can always increase it to get a faster transaction ...

Comment: Thanks but why is this required web3.eth.getGasPrice(function(error, result){  ? Can't we simply use Coursetro.methods.setFile.(identifier, fileName, "hash...").estimateGas....... ?

Comment: yeah yeah you can, it was more to illustrate how to estimate the median transaction cost

Comment: + 1 Thanks. How to specify a gas limit here ?

Comment: `estimateGas` returns the gasLimit, you estimate the cost by calculating the gasLimit (computation cost of the transaction in unit) * gasPrice (reward by gas unit) - Bigger is the reward, faster is the transaction.

Comment: I got the point. I want to specify my own gas limit(maximum gas I want to spend) after getting an estimate(estimate x 1.5 maybe) so as to make sure not much ether/gas is spent on a single transaction.

Comment: Once you have the gas estimation _x_ and the gas price you are willing to pay _y_, you can call the function (send the transaction) by doing `MyContract.MyFunction(arg1, arg2, {from: 0x, gasPrice: y, gas: x}, (tx) => console.log(tx))` | [more info](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#parameters-25)